# Dataweave 2 - Output multiple JSON by line

Tags: mule, transformation, dataweave

My **input** is a **Array of Objects** that I want to **map** to a **JSON object**.

I want **each JSON object to be line per line** and the JSON set in the **same payload**.

My Dataweave code:

```
 %dw 2.0
 output application/json indent = false
 ---
 payload map (payload, indexOfPayload ) -> {
     id: payload.externalid_c,
     surname: payload.surname__c
         platform: payload.platform__c
 }
```

Example output I want:

```
 {"id": "demo", "surname": "anypoint", "platform": "testing"}
 {"id": "demo2", "surname": "studio", "platform": "apple"}
 {"id": "demo3", "surname": "windows", "platform": "microsoft"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`write` as json first to use the writer property to remove indentation, join the list items together seperated by a new line and output as text/plain(cannot use json as its not valid json)

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
payload map ((item, index) -> 
    write({id: item.externalid_c,
    surname: item.surname__c,
    platform: item.platform__c
    }, "application/json", {"indent":false}) 

) joinBy  '\r'
```

Comment: It returns `"Message               : "You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 
  1: Binary ("" as Binary {mediaType: "*/*; charset=UTF-8", encoding: "UTF-8", mimeType: "...)
  2: Function ((item:Any, index:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Array
  2: Function`

Comment: That is because your input payload doesn't have the mimetype set. Check that on the source of the payload you specify is application/json

Answer (score 3):

Hi you need to use the *write* function and output it as text plain as the desire output is not a valid json

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
payload map ((value, index) -> write(value, "application/json", {indent: false})) joinBy  "\n"
```

This example shows you how to do it.